# SQL Server Stored procedure issue -file is being used by another process

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL Server Stored procedure that will dynamically create job every minute, this job will execute a powershell script every time it runs. The problem is here when the one job is executing the Powershell script the other job getting failed with error : the file is being used by another process(since the previous job is executing it). Is there any way to avoid such issue, please help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Comment: Whats the bigger picture - what are you trying to do here? Is it the powershell file that is being locked or is it some other file that is used by powershell being locked?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Yes, it is powershell file that is being locked

Comment: So the .ps1 file? Are you creating it dynamically each time? Do actually you need to ? What is the exact error?

Comment: No, the .ps1 file is already there in a folder, every minute when the t-sql stored procedure is executed in turn a new agent job will be created and executed..during execution of this job it will read and execute this .ps1 file from the folder. In the middle of execution of this .ps1 file by the first job, the second job unable to execute the same .ps1 file from the same location, so getting unable to access .ps1 file because it is locked by some other process error.

Comment: Could anyone help me to resolve issue...

Comment: It seems strange that it would need that level of locking. What happens if you make the .ps1 file read only. Does the first one fail? I'm also curious as to why you need to create dynamic SQL Agent jobs. Maybe the dynamically created one doesn't have sufficient rights. Can you just create two static SQL Agent jobs?